# Two step encryption

Tags: encryption, cryptography

Consider the following user case:

1. I have some sensitive data (eg: credit card number)
2. I encrypt this data and store it in the database
3. Now I want to send this data to a user X, but I **don't** want to:

   1. Decrypt this data before sending
   2. Give user X *my* key used for decrypting stored data

I would like to give to user X his own private key and use one more round of encryption on the encrypted data before I send it to him.

Is there encryption algorithm which changes the decryption key with each each subsequent encryption round? Something that looks like this:

```
Ct = Encrypt(KeyA, Pt)   # I store Ct in the database

CtB = Encrypt(KeyB, Ct)  # I now encrypt it with different key and 
                         # send CtB along with a private key KeyC to the user
                         # KeyC is derived from KeyB

Pt = Decrypt(KeyC, CtB)  # the user can now use this KeyC to get the original data
```

With this, I can create different ciphertexts for each user, stopping them from sharing keys. This also means data would never be in plaintext form on the server.

Use case is only theoretical and I know there are different solutions appropriate for such situation.

Comment: If you don't want to give the user the ability to decrypt it why send the information at all?  Why are you storing data that you encrypt but also need to transmit, something seems odd, sounds like you shouldn't even collect this information.

Comment: @Ramhound
Read the question first. I want to give the user the ability to decrypt data. I'm looking for an algorithm in which data can be encrypted recursively and decryption key will change with each subsequent encryption. So it would work kind of like XOR but in form of more advanced/safe encryption algorithm

Comment: I think you're mixing up *what* you want done with a proposed *how* you want it done.  One of the rules is "don't do your own crypto; re-use someone elses."

Comment: @onlineapplab.com If you don't want to be able to decrypt the data on the server, then why don't you simply have the user encrypt it and then only transmit it already encrypted and then the server never knows how to decrypt it.  I guess I'm still a little fuzzy on the theoretical use case.  I'm wondering if there is a simpler way to accomplish the same objective though.

Comment: @AJHenderson
1 If data has to be decrypted before sending to the user then it is available in a decrypted form on the server 
2 If I send original decryption key user can share this key and anyone can use to decrypt data.
So I was thinking about scenario where stored data is never decrypted and it can be encrypted again with different key which will generate also different key for the decryption. In such case I can send this data to different users without ever decrypting it or sharing original decryption key. 
It is theoretical question about algorithms.

Comment: @onlineapplab.com Why does it matter if different users can share the decryption key? If the user is able to decrypt data, why would they even bother sharing the key? They could just share the decrypted data itself. I understand the question, but the use case is just not there.

Comment: @onlineapplab.com - so you want to be able to encrypt a value from the user and when you give it back to the user you don't want the user to be able to decrypt it?  Then why are you giving the data to the user at all.  A server should only hand out the data to a third party that should be able to make use of it.  If you want to protect it in a way that the user can handle it to give it to another service but not let the user know about what is in it, there are also ways to do that (I suggest reading up on Kerberos.)

Comment: @onlineapplab.com Hitting on what Null said, I think that the system you describe, while I believe it may be theoretically possible(mathematically) though not necessarily secure, is not actually practical for any use.  There are simpler ways to accomplish any goal I could see this kind of system being used for.

Comment: @Null
For example: if we have many users with different access levels then using one user key it is not possible to decrypt data sent to the other user

Comment: @onlineapplab.com The solution is simple: use a different symmetric key for each user. Of course this means you'd have to decrypt data on the server, but I don't see much advantage in not doing so.

Comment: @AJHenderson
Read the question again. I have encryption key enA and enB and decryption key deC 
deC(enB(enA('Hello World'))) = 'Hello World'
On server is store data as enA('Hello world') and send to user as enB(enA('Hello world')). User is using deC key to decrypt the data

Comment: @onlineapplab Where does deC come from?  If the server generates it, then there is no security gain over the server decrypting and re-encrypting with a session key, so it's just needless complexity (and complexity breeds insecurity.)

Comment: @AJHenderson
There is a security gain as the decrypted data will not be available on the server so even if the server is compromised there will be only encrypted data available without the decryption key.
Anyway how is it relevant to answering this question? Do you know such algorithm or not?

Comment: @onlineapplab - The server generates the decryption key, therefore deC is available to the attacker if the server is compromised unless there is some other source of deC.

Comment: @AJHenderson
deC is assigned to the user so it is not stored on the server

Comment: @onlineapplab.com - If deC is held by the user, then what is the gain over simply using a symmetric encryption on the client side where the server never has the key?  The client is having to encrypt it with a key of their choice and decrypt it with a key that they are responsible to store.

Comment: @AJHenderson
How about many users accessing the same data?

Comment: @onlineapplab.com - so you are trying to figure out if there is a system that could not give the server the ability to decrypt, but allow the original user to perform an additional encryption and generate a key that they could give to a third party to allow them to decrypt it?  In this case, I think Key A would have to be presented or the algorithm wouldn't be secure.  At that point, it would be possible for whatever system possesses Key A to decrypt it, so it might as well be re-encrypted with a non-bounded Key C which wouldn't possibly have a weakness that could reveal Key B or Key A.

Comment: Additional requirement for such algorithm would be that having keys B and C it is not possible to calculate key A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like what you are asking about is probably mathematically possible, but it would likely be hard (and maybe impossible) to find a way to do it such that it is both mathematically true and hard to guess.  I suspect you are unlikely to find an existing system that meets your exact specifications as I can not think of any use case that couldn't be more effectively handled using much simpler applications of common cryptographic algorithms.

If you have a particular case that you can think of that you think this would handle that couldn't otherwise be handled, then perhaps posting that use case scenario (even if theoretical) would help better answer your question.  It also might be worth bringing up the idea over on Cryptography or even Math since they tend to deal more with the theoretical math side of things if that is where your interests lie.

Answer (score 2):

@AJ Henderson includes a reasonable answer; I'm going to try to explain more clearly.

1) Your question mixes what you want done (secure storage and transmission) with how you want to do it (two step encryption).

2) If you want to store the information securely, encrypt it with a symmetric key (choose a new symmetric key for every "thing" you want to store).  Now encrypt the symmetric key with a public key and store that.

3) if you want to share the information:
3a) Decrypt the symmetric key, and encrypt it with the recipients public key.
3b) Send the encrypted data along with the symmetric key encrypted by the recipients public key.

The recipient (and only the recipient) can use their private key to decrypt the information.  At no time is data transmitted in the clear.

I *think* that answers *what* you want done, although the *how* is different.

Comment: In 3a-3b I share key used for data storage encryption and I don't want to do this. I need algorithm which could be used recursively so with which subsequent encryption we will have different encryption key. Mu question is does such algorithm exist?

Comment: should be "with each subsequent encryption we will have different decryption key"

Comment: Why do you want to change the encryption key for each encryption?

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace If I understand the OP correctly, they want to give each user a different private key with which they can decrypt the ciphertext and get the original data back. This also means each user gets a different ciphertext. The result is now users can't share keys. My question to the OP is: in this case, why would they bother sharing the keys, when they can just share the original plaintext?

Comment: @Null
The point is to avoid decrypting the data on the server

Comment: @onlineapplab.com Why would that be a problem? You'd still be able to decrypt data stored on the database if you had the original key, right?

Comment: @Null
What if for example you cannot be sure about security of the server. You keep only encrypted data there an keys used for further encryption before sending it to the users. Even if someone will get full control of your server there will not be able to get your data

Answer (score 0):

First, you should never store data encrypted with a public/private key system.  Public/Private key cryptography is significantly more expensive to use and in general provides far less security for the key-length being used and are far more processor intensive.  Your best bet is to encrypt a data storage key using a public/private key system and use the symmetric data storage key for your encrypted storage.  It is then possible to do what you are looking for.

Encryption, server generates a new data storage key and encrypts the CC number.  Data storage key is encrypted with the public key of the server and stored.  When you want to send the data to user X, you use the server's private key to decrypt the data storage key and re-encrypt the data storage key with user X's public key.  User X can now access the symmetric data storage key in an encrypted state and can then decrypt  it locally to be able to decrypt the symmetrically encrypted data.

Comment: I want to avoid step of decrypting data before sending it to the user. Does such algorithm exist?

Comment: "public/Private key cryptography grows significantly weaker if a large amount of semi-predictable data is stored using it." [citation needed] (I'm pretty sure this is not true)

Comment: @onlineapplab.com - There is no safe way to transmit the information you want to send to another user if your using a public/private cryptography.  You need to double check if you really need to store this type of information if you have a need to transmit it to another user.

Comment: There is some good stuff in this answer, but we need to separate the wheat from the chaff.  The second paragraph answers the poster's question; the first paragraph mixes assertions with sound advice.

Comment: @CodesInChaos The only reference I have off the top of my head for that assertion is my college professor who knew his stuff pretty well.  It could be wrong, but that was how I was taught it in a dedicated crypto class.  As I recall it had to do with the length of predictable data resulting in certain mathematical attacks that could optimize guessing the factoring.  This is from 6 years ago though, so I could be foggy and it probably doesn't apply to all asymmetric cryptosystems.

Comment: 1) Since you only need to know the public key to encrypt, the attacker could trivial create those large amounts of predictable data himself. 2) Correct padding eliminates most weaknesses in RSA. Some beginner explanations are about paddingless RSA, but that's broken in many ways and should not be used in practice.

Comment: @onlineapplab.com Sorry if the end of my answer wasn't fully clear.  If the public key for the user was generated on the user's machine, then the data encryption key can be sent encrypted to the user with the user's public key.  Only the user can decrypt it locally (on their machine).  Then the data itself can be sent with the symmetric encryption and since the user has the symmetric data key for that record, they can then decrypt it.  It is worth noting that in this type of system it is important that every record have its own symmetric key.

Comment: @CodesInChaos - hmm, I will have to try and dig up my notes for more information about what it was, but you bring up a good point about the public key.  It wasn't really a beginner class (it was a graduate level class), but it may have also been that it was an attack on the encryption rather than the key.  ie, it resulted in discovery of data if sufficient length is encrypted with predictable elements.  Either way, you've peaked my curiosity to try and refresh myself on the details of what I'm thinking of or if I'm simply forgetting.  Thanks.

Comment: @Onlineapplab.com Rereading your question I see you don't want to send the data storage key, you could do a decryption on the server with the data storage key, re-encrypt with a session data key and then send the session data key encrypted payload to the user with the session data key protected by their public key.  Alternately, if possible, just use an SSL connection and a web service.  It will do this (the transmission part) for you.

Comment: @AJHenderson
I've edited the question to clarify it.
I don't want to send my decryption key and I don't want to decrypt the data either.

Comment: @onlineapplab.com You have good answers for methods to deal with storing encrypted data in general and methods for sending that data while preserving the encryption to another party.  But you still say you don't want to decrypt the data and you don't want to send the key, can you explain why?  Someone might be able to provide better answers if you can edit your question to provide more information about the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: @pipTheGeek
I don't have any real problem to solve right now it rather a theoretical question about encryption algorithms